# How can I Buffer stored pictures from InputStream

Tags: android, image, url, imageview

I loaded all photos (.jpg format) from the url and show them using InputStream. So, I want to save 3 images before, and 3 images after the current index of imageview, into the buffer to use them later. How can I do that?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know one could show images with InputStream. I also didn't know that imageview has a current index.

Comment: I have no idea what do you want to achieve, could you explain a little more? Also in case what you need is caching images, check out `Universal Image Loader`

Comment: I think I can also use this, so how can I use Universal Image Loader?